# Dodge Journey Crew GPS activation

Tags: dodge, gps

My brother in law got a Dodge Journey Crew 2013, pretty fancy and well-equipped, with a huge screen inside. He has the rear-view camera and he can play DVDs on his screen, he's got the wheel pressure data, etc. All's perfect, except he's got no GPS. I heard that these cars come either without the rear-camera nor GPS, or with both. When he asked at his dealership, they said that he has to pay $700 to activate the GPS. I find it ridiculous: an extra gadget would cost about $100 and it will do the job perfectly. The only reason to go with the built-in GPS is to avoid extra stuff on the dashboard. So, is there a way to activate the GPS or does he have to pay $700 anyway?

Comment: What year is the Journey? I assume it's new, but that could be new 2014 or new 2015 or new to him some other year.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that... It's 2013

Comment: Looks like it's a purchase item: [Look Here](http://chryslergroup.navigation.com/zidE00000776209/en_US/ChryslerNA/USD?ProgramUUID=m7QK5GXJxcIAAAFNAjtsT8Rl&utm_campaign=CHRYSLERVP30515&utm_medium=DM&utm_source=CHR-DM1-VP3-0515)

Comment: Personally, if it were me, I'd mount my smart phone on the dash and use it. The ones which come with the vehicles become out of date, then you need to purchase the map updates, whereas Google updates their maps all the time for free. It's neat to have it on the dash, but why pay for it if you don't have to.

Comment: @Paulster2 You can never match the neat look and things like steering wheel control of a built-in unit. I agree that they become outdated pretty quick. Even a cheap tablet has better touch screen than most of these units.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a purchase item: [Look Here](http://chryslergroup.navigation.com/zidE00000776209/en_US/ChryslerNA/USD?ProgramUUID=m7QK5GXJxcIAAAFNAjtsT8Rl&utm_campaign=CHRYSLERVP30515&utm_medium=DM&utm_source=CHR-DM1-VP3-0515)

Personally, if it were me, I'd mount my smart phone on the dash and use it. The ones which come with the vehicles become out of date, then you need to purchase the map updates, whereas Google updates their maps all the time for free. It's neat to have it on the dash, but why pay for it if you don't have to.